# Debugging hangs with "Application is waiting for debugger to attach" on Android with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I know that this issued has been assessed a number of times but I can not resolve it.
I'm using Eclipse v. 4.2.2, Android API 19, Windows 7 64 bit.
I have the same issue on both a Kitkat virtual device and a Nexus 5 device. 
I'm trying to debug an almost empty application and the last Console output is always:

```
[2014-06-04 11:56:03 - delme] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.delme' on port 8611
[2014-06-04 11:56:04 - delme] Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM
```

I tried all the following steps with no success:

- adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>`
- adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` in host configuration file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)
- only 1 instance of eclipse was open
- only 1 device is connected
- restarted Eclipse and windows and adb kill-server and rebooted the pc
- restarted the device

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does 'adb devices' say?

Comment: `List of devices attached
042b7ff3251fb109        device`

Comment: Nexus drivers installed?

Comment: Yes, every application does run well from eclipse without debugging activates. And the same does happens with the virtual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, resolved the issue by installing a new Eclipse-ADT bundle. 
My old version was a Juno with ADT manually added, but I don't know what was the problem.